# MySql stored procedure run time keeps increasing with every call

Tags: mysql

I have MySql workbench 8.0 and mySql version 8.0.16 on my windows 10 machine.

Every time I make a call to a stored procedure, the duration to retrieve the result set increases.

As you can see, after a few calls the duration increased from 0.297 seconds to over 5 seconds.[image]

Code for the stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test`(IN startDate date, IN endDate date)
BEGIN

DECLARE sDate date;
SET sDate =startDate; 

startLoop:WHILE sDate <= endDate DO 
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  user_schedule where user_id = 11  and date=sDate) THEN
    BEGIN
        #empty for testing purpose
    END;
    END IF;
    SET sDate=DATE_ADD(sDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY);  #increment by 1 day
END WHILE startLoop;
END
```

I can't see any memory leak issue, or anything that might cause this delay after every call.